# Flipper React Native Xcode iOS Simulator Version Mismatch

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

I'm getting the following error about mismatched Xcode versions. However, it doesn't seem to make sense. The UUID is the "Indentifier" of the simulator that is running, not any folder I can switch to. I've found a similar bug, but since it is closed, and old, I don't think I'll get much of a response over there: https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/1925#issuecomment-1030495731

I've tried running all the suggested commands with and without `sudo` and nothing helps. This looks like it might be an Xcode workspace configuration issue since I've not had these problems with other React Native applications.

> Xcode version mismatch
> Xcode version mismatch: Simulator is running from "286DC512-9354-4D32-A0F3-B354C61BD6B7/Contents/Developer" while Xcode CLI is "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer". Running "xcode-select --switch 286DC512-9354-4D32-A0F3-B354C61BD6B7/Contents/Developer" can fix this. For example: "sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"

- Xcode version 13.2.1
- Flipper version 0.132.0 (50.0.0)
- iOS version 15.2
- iPhone 11

Answer (score 2):

I've believe that is related with this version 0.132. I've downgrade my version from 0.132 to 0.113 (version that I was using). And everything is working fine.

You can find more releases here https://github.com/facebook/flipper/releases

I'm still looking for a solution to this on version 0.132.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and the error was gone once i upgraded to flipper 0.135.0